# Using file extension content negotiation with spring security plugin?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, annotations, spring-security

I'm trying to use the latest spring security plugin for grails, but I've hit a little bump.

I have a controller with this method:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
def query = {
}
```

When I hit `http://localhost:8080/myApp/myController/query`, I get prompted for authorization as appropriate. However, I need to do content type negotiation via the filename extension. Using

`grails.mime.file.extensions=true`

I can use the same UrlMappings and get to my controller method via `.../myApp/myController/query.js?params=blah`. **However**, I am not prompted for authentication, and either the request goes through automatically or fails, depending on how I've set `grails.plugins.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule`

How can I use file type negotiation with the spring security plugin?

Comment: You can vote for this JIRA issue http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-151 so hopefully the bug gets fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off `grails.mime.file.extensions` and add this filter:

```
class FileExtensionContentNegotiationFilters {
    final static String DEFAULT_FORMAT = "js"
    def filters = {
        all(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                addFormatToRequestByFileExtension(request)
            }
            after = {
            }
            afterView = {
            }
        }
    }

    protected addFormatToRequestByFileExtension(def request) {
        String suffix = getSuffixFromPath(request.forwardURI)
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(suffix)

        if (extension.isEmpty()) {
            request[GrailsApplicationAttributes.CONTENT_FORMAT] = DEFAULT_FORMAT
        }
        else {
            request[GrailsApplicationAttributes.CONTENT_FORMAT] = extension
        }
    }

    protected String getSuffixFromPath(String pathWithoutParams) {
        int lastSlash = pathWithoutParams.lastIndexOf("/")

        if (lastSlash < 0) {
            return ""
        }

        return pathWithoutParams.substring(lastSlash + 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution above does not work for me as expected. A 404 response is generated when I request an URL with extension.

I come with another solution that does not need to turn off `grails.mime.file.extensions` and does not need an extra Filter. Instead, it's a modification of the plugin's class `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition`. What you need to do is to edit the method `determineUrl` as shown below (look at the comments to identify the changes):

```
@Override
protected String determineUrl(final FilterInvocation filterInvocation) {
    HttpServletRequest request = filterInvocation.getHttpRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = filterInvocation.getHttpResponse();

    GrailsWebRequest existingRequest = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest();

    String requestUrl = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());

    /** The following 2 lines were added */
    int indexOfPeriod = requestUrl.indexOf('.');
    String requestUrlForMatching = (indexOfPeriod != -1) ? requestUrl.substring(0, indexOfPeriod) : requestUrl;

    String url = null;
    try {
        GrailsWebRequest grailsRequest = new GrailsWebRequest(request, response,
                ServletContextHolder.getServletContext());
        WebUtils.storeGrailsWebRequest(grailsRequest);

        Map<String, Object> savedParams = copyParams(grailsRequest);

        /* Use requestUrlForMatching instead of requestUrl */
        for (UrlMappingInfo mapping : _urlMappingsHolder.matchAll(requestUrlForMatching)) {
            configureMapping(mapping, grailsRequest, savedParams);

            url = findGrailsUrl(mapping);
            if (url != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (existingRequest == null) {
            WebUtils.clearGrailsWebRequest();
        }
        else {
            WebUtils.storeGrailsWebRequest(existingRequest);
        }
    }

    if (!StringUtils.hasLength(url)) {
        // probably css/js/image
        url = requestUrl;
    }

    return lowercaseAndStripQuerystring(url);
}
```

The problem is that URLs with extensions do not match any URL in `UrlMappings` using `UrlMappingsHolder.matchAll` method. So, the solution is to ommit the extension prior to look for matches. With this changes everything works as expected.

I also create a pull request with the fix available at https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/pull/24

You can see the changes at https://github.com/arcesino/grails-spring-security-core/commit/19f87168ec4422b4fe06cc6914adeb1bae4b8752

Tested with version 1.2.7.3